# Корректность реализации функции Split

Tags: c++, функции, split

Попытался создать функцию `split()` чтоб разделить строку на слова и записать их в массив. Подскажите, корректен ли данный код, или что то не так?

```
void split(string str,vector<int>& mas,char delim){
int step=0;
string str1="";
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    str1+=str[i];
    if(str[i]==delim){
        mas.push_back(stoi(str1));
        str1="";
    }
}
}
```

Код рабочий, но все же.

Comment: А зачем вам `delim`, если вы его не используете нигде? Тогда уже сравнивайте с  `delim` `str[i]`, т.е. `if(str[i]==delim)`

Comment: "разделить строку на слова и записать их в массив"? Во-первых, у вас в коде "в массив" записываются не слова, а числа, полученные через `stoi`. Во-вторых, код будет делать ерунду, если во входной строке будут идти несколько разделителей подряд. В-третьих, как уже было замечено, что такое `delim` и почему он не используется в коде вообще?